# How to calculate the limit of a sum

Tags: calculus, summation

For this question, I can't really seem to get the final answer. I get stuck on the step right before you take the limits. Can anyone please help me out?

$$\begin{align}\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^n (k^2+k+1)
& =\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sum_{k=0}^n k^2 + \sum_{k=0}^n k + \sum_{k=0}^n 1)\\
& =\lim_{n\to \infty}(\frac{n(2n+1)(n+1)}{6} + \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + n)\\
& = \lim_{n\to \infty}(\frac{2n^3+6n^2+10n}{6})
\end{align}$$

Comment: Hint: $\sum_{k=0}^n (k^2+k+1) \ge n^2+n+1 \ge n\,$. Now, what is $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} n\,$?

Comment: Seriously?  None of those series converges!

Comment: I'm not really sure where you're going with this. n is infinity isn't it?

Comment: @deezy Right, and so is your limit, in other words it diverges to $+\infty\,$.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have to compute $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{k=0}^n (k^2+k+1)$ instead? Without the $1/n^3$, just note that $\sum_{k=0}^n(k^2+k+1)\ge n+1$, so the limit is infinity.

Comment: There is no 1/n^3. Not sure where that came from

Comment: @deezy If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, as @egreg already noted, the question as stated does not make sense, and furthermore no source is given for it.

Comment: @deezy Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks! http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png

Answer (score 3):

Simply note that

$$\frac{2n^3+6n^2+10n}{6} \ge\frac{0+0+10n}{6} = \frac53n\ge n\to +\infty$$

Comment: where do we show the >n in the step?

Comment: @deezy I've added one step!

Comment: Where did the two zeros come from?

Comment: @deezy They come from the fact that $n$ is positive when you are taking the limit.

Comment: $2n^3>0$ and $6n^2>0$ thus $2n^3+6n^2+10n>0+0+10n$ it's a very trivial fact in this case

Comment: Shouldn't 10n>0 as well then?

Comment: Since you ave k=0 it should be $\ge$, I fix it!

Comment: @deezy the final result doesn't change

Comment: @deezy yes but if we put all 0 we can't prove that it goes to $\infty$

Comment: So we can put any of them to be zero?

Comment: @deezy it's a trick to show that the quantity is greater than n and thus goes to $\infty$, there are many ways to show that, anything of special with this one

Comment: @deezy of course, for example $$\frac{2n^3+6n^2+10n}{6} \ge\frac{0+6n^2+0}{6} = n^2\ge n\to +\infty$$

Comment: @deezy If we had $$\frac{2n^3+6n^2+10n}{1000}$$ it would be a little bit more difficult, but the idea is the same

Comment: So we just need to show that one of them is bigger or equal to n?

Comment: @deezy in general you need to show that all the quantity is greater to something that goes to infinity, in this case n is a good and simple choice, it is the squeeze theorem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1057748/squeeze-theorem-with-infinite-limits

Answer (score 0):

For the final calculation of the final limit expression, it simply is :

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\bigg(\frac{2n^3+6n^2+10n}{6}\bigg)=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{3}n^3 = \infty$$

There is a rule for polynomial limits to infinity and it states that the limit of a polynomial at $\infty$ is simply the limit of the highest power term. This happens because the bigger the power gets, the biggest the impact it has on a really big value.

Comment: So what about $6n^2$ and 10n then?

Comment: As mentioned, the highest degree of power term makes the difference. But take a look into that as well, since this is a simple case with positive signs :
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\bigg(\frac{2n^3+6n^2+10n}{6}\bigg)=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{3}n^3 = \infty = \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{3}n^3 + \lim_{x\to \infty} n^2 + \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{10}{6}n = \infty $$
since all of the seperate limits tend to $\infty$ as well.

Comment: Ok that makes sense to me now, so then could I write it as the sum then?

Comment: @deezy Yes, you could expand it by the sum and it's correct in this specific case, but it isn't the best way generally since if it had minus signs it would complicate things !