# Limit calculation: $\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{x \ln x}{1 - \sin x}$

Tags: limits

I have to calculate the following limit

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{x \ln x}{1 - \sin x}$$

According Wolfram Alpha the limit exists and is $+\infty$ but I think it does not exist since $\lim_{x \to +\infty} 1 - \sin x$ does not exist. So: why am I wrong?

Comment: You are not wrong, wolfram is

Comment: No, Wolfram is correct. @NinadMunshi

Comment: @ThomasAndrews mind explaining the little subsequence of poles? For example I would not say $\lim_{x\to\infty}x\sec^2x$ exists either for the same reason.

Comment: @NinadMunshi see my answer. Functions which have undefined values don’t preclude limits as $x\to\infty,$ unless the domain 8# bounded.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews you can claim whatever you want, but I haven't seen a source that defines a limit in the $x>M$ way that would allow this. I'm not saying it's not practical but it's very haphazard.

Comment: @NinadMunshi you certainly have, although you haven’t notice. Any integer sequence limit is exactly such a case. $$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$$

Comment: @NinadMunshi Alternatively, in this case, you can define the function as a continuous function$(0,\infty)\to(-\infty,+\infty]$ and get definitions for the points where it previously undefined. Then you still get a limit as $x\to\infty.$

Comment: The extended reals, $X=\mathbb R\cup\{\pm\infty\},$ are just another metric space/topology, and we get an easy definition of $\lim_{x\to+\infty} f(x)$ for any domain  of $f$ which is not isolated from $+\infty.$

Comment: The sequence limit and the real limit generalize to functions with totally ordered domain. @NinadMunshi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n}{2+\pm (-1)^n}$$ is infinity even though the denominator does not converge.

The real problem with your function is that it isn’t defined for all of $\mathbb R.$ But if $f$ is a function defined on a subset of $\mathbb R$ with no real upper bound, we can still define $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x).$

In your case, you easily get, where $f$ is defined, and $x>1,$ $$f(x)=\frac{x\ln x}{1-\sin x}\geq \frac{x\ln x}{2},$$ since $0<1-\sin x\leq 2$ in the domain of $f.$

Since $\frac{x\ln x}2\to\infty,$ this means $f(x)\to\infty.$

Comment: I can't understand why from $\frac{x \ln x}{2} \to \infty$ and $\frac{x \ln x}{1 - \sin x} \ge \frac{x \ln x}{2}$ follows the final result. What theorem did you use?

Comment: If $g(x)\to+\infty$ and $f(x)\geq g(x)$ for all $x>M,$ for some $M,$ then $f(x)\to+\infty.$ That is easy to prove from the definition. @rookie_of_math

Comment: @rookie_of_math Refer to [squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1057748/squeeze-theorem-with-infinite-limits).

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks

Comment: @user Thank you too

Answer (score 3):

The quotient $\dfrac{x\ln(x)}{1-\sin(x)}$ is undefined when $x\in\dfrac\pi2+2\pi\Bbb Z$. Otherwise, $1-\sin(x)\leqslant2$, and therefore$$\frac{x\ln(x)}{1-\sin(x)}\geqslant\frac{x\ln(x)}2.\tag1$$Since$$\lim_{x\to\infty}x\ln(x)=\infty,$$it follows from $(1)$ that$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x\ln(x)}{1-\sin(x)}=\infty$$too.

Comment: I can't understand why from $\lim_{x \to \infty} x \ln x = \infty$ and $(1)$ follows the final result. What theorem did you use?

Comment: $$\lim_{x\to\infty}x\ln(x)=\infty\implies\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x\ln(x)}2=\infty\implies\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x\ln(x)}{1-\sin(x)}=\infty$$

Comment: But when $x \to \infty$, I don't have $2 = 1 - \sin x$. I have that $1 - \sin x$ oscillates between $0$ and $2$.

Comment: Your answer is the same as Thomas Andrews. Am I right? So your answer uses the same theorem. Right? i.e. if $f(x) \ge g(x)$ and $g(x) \to \infty$, then $f(x) \to \infty$. Right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. And I never claimed that $2=1-\sin x$, only that $2\geqslant1-\sin x$.

Comment: OK. Perfect. Thanks.