# Evaluate $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} \left(\sqrt[n]{n + x} - \sqrt[n]{x}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, rationalising-denominator

Is there a way to evaluate the following limit without resorting to [power series expansion](https://brilliant.org/wiki/fractional-binomial-theorem/)?

$$\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} \left(\sqrt[n]{n + x} - \sqrt[n]{x}\right), \quad\text{ $n$ is a positive integer greater than 1.}$$

I've attempted approaching the problem using Squeeze Theorem like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1057748/squeeze-theorem-with-infinite-limits) but to no avail.

**EDIT:** Preferably, the solution should only involve inequalities with appealing to asymptotics or approximation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality)

$$\sqrt[n]{n + x} =\sqrt[n]{ x}\left(1+\frac n x\right)^{\frac 1n} \le \sqrt[n]{ x}\left(1+\frac 1n\frac n x\right)=\sqrt[n]{ x}\left(1+\frac 1 x\right)$$

then

$$0\le \sqrt[n]{n + x} - \sqrt[n]{x}\le \frac 1 {x^{1-\frac1n}} $$

Answer (score 2):

As $x\to+\infty$,$$\left(\sqrt[n]{n + x} - \sqrt[n]{x}\right)=x^{1/n}\left(\left(1+\frac nx\right)^{1/n}-1\right)\sim x^{\frac1n-1}\to0.$$

Answer (score 2):

Using
$$ a^n-b^n=(a-b)\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a^{n-k}b^k, \sqrt[n]{n+x}\ge\sqrt[n]{x} $$
one has
$$0<\sqrt[n]{n + x} - \sqrt[n]{x}=\frac{\left(\sqrt[n]{n + x} - \sqrt[n]{x}\right)\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sqrt[n]{n+x}^{n-k}\sqrt[n]{x}^k}{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sqrt[n]{n+x}^{n-k}\sqrt[n]{x}^k}\le\frac{n}{nx}=\frac1x $$
which implies the limit.